# How to create a table out of the existing table?

Tags: oracle, create-table

So I am having a big table of AbstractID, SentenceID, WordID, and Word. Some words show in multiple files. I would like to count how many files every word shows, and then create a new table of with Word and Count. Below is a piece of my data.
[image]

My sql query is below:

```
CREATE TABLE WORDLIST(WORD, TOTALCOUNT) AS
(
  SELECT WORD FROM ASSIGNMENT2 WHERE
  (
    SELECT WORD, COUNT(*) FROM (select DISTINCT FILEID, WORD FROM ASSIGNMENT2)
    GROUP BY WORD ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC));
```

It is giving me an error:
"Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:
*Action:"

How do I correct this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're rather overcomplicating the query. The error is because your outer `where` clause doesn't have a condition; you're selecting multiple things, which isn't right anyway, but then not comparing those to anything. And you don't need to enclose the query in a set of parentheses.

You can just do:

```
CREATE TABLE WORDLIST (WORD, TOTALCOUNT) AS
SELECT WORD, COUNT(DISTINCT FILEID)
FROM ASSIGNMENT2
GROUP BY WORD;
```

There's no point ordering the query as it won't affect future queries against the new table - you still have to order those, as there is no inherent order of rows within the table. (And I think an `order by` will cause an error in a create-as statement, but can't immediately check that).

Creating a table to hold this information seems odd though as it will go out of date quickly. Perhaps you wanted a view really?

Comment: I ordered it because I want to remove words with highest and lowest frequency.

Comment: Now it is giving me this error message: `Error at Command Line:8 Column:14
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
*Cause:    
*Action:` I tried to do it before, now sure if SQL already created a WORDLIST table. Do you know how I check this? Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: @Q-ximi - it won't have created the table from what was in your question, but maybe you tried before that. Check with `select object_type, object_name from user_objects where object_name = 'WORDLIST'`, in case something except a table has that name; or just `describe wordlist` in SQL*Plus to see the current table definition. If you need to, and you're sure, you can `drop table wordlist`. Make sure you know what you are going to drop though.

Comment: Ordering on insert won't help you find the highest and lowest frequency.

Comment: Looks like I already created the table but I don't where it is. I tried to use a different table name `WORDCOUNT`, this time it gives me a new error:`Error report:
SQL Command: table WORDCOUNT
Failed: Warning: execution completed with warning`.

Comment: [Works for me me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f1631/2); not sure what you're doing differently? Also wonder what client you're using, you don't normally see a 'with warning' from `create table`. Try `show errors`, or look in the `user_errors` table, but both only usually refer to stored PL/SQL errors.

Comment: Now I am trying to create a view in stead of a table with your query. The same problem. It keeps telling me that the table is already created but I can not find it from the left sidebar where all tables are listed. Could you please point out to me where to find it and how to keep working on it? Thanks a lot.